# How do i enable data on jtable form

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2013, jquery-jtable

My AJAX Jtable form loads in a partial view but on clicking add or edit the form displays but all fields but they are grayed out or disabled.  I cant add new record or edit existing.  I am using CS 2013; jtable 2.4.0, jquery 1.11.4

Answer (score 0):

In JTable you can provide add/edit/list/get actions like

```
$('#DivID').jtable({
        paging: true,
        sorting: true,
        defaultSorting: 'UpdateTime DESC',
        pageSize: $("#hidPageSize").val(),
        pageList: 'normal',
        pageSizeChangeArea: true,
        resizable: true,
        scrollable: true,
        type: 'POST',
        title: 'Some title',
        actions: {
            listAction: 'ListActionName',
            createAction: 'AddActionName',
            updateAction: 'UpdateActionName',
            deleteAction: 'DeleteActionName'
        },
        fields: {
```

Also for the fields you can restrict edit by

```
fieldName: {
                title: "Some Title",
                edit:true,
                inputClass: validationClass
            },
```

This should work

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#OnGoingTable').jtable({
            paging: true,
            title: 'Capture, Edit and View Ongoing Procurements',
            actions: {
                listAction: '/PDUDocument/PDUDocumentList',
                updateAction: '/PDUDocument/UpdateDocToOngoingProcurement',
                createAction: '/PDUDocument/AddDocToOngoingProcurement'
            },
  fields: {

                DocRefNo_ID: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    list: false
                },